# Restore "views" sort order for answers in user profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

We used to able to sort answers in a user profile by *view*, just like questions:

[image: Screenshot of sort order for questions]

This functionality was removed. I can only guess why, but I assume it's because it's misleading -- [the system records *question views*, not *answer views*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49344/151367). If you answer a popular question late, it was viewed thousands of times – but your answer wasn't (and let's ignore that answers aren't read equally for now).

One goal of these sites is to provide **correct information even long after the question was originally asked**. In fact, **we discourage repetition**, even just to get current information: If you ask a question *again*, it gets closed as duplicate. We have badges like *Archaeologist* that specifically **reward fixing and updating old content**. We allow anyone to suggest edits to questions and answers to get readers to **improve wrong or outdated content**.

Suppose, as a committed contributor, you not only want to provide a steady stream of *new answers*, but also want to make sure your existing answers **stay relevant** and therefore valuable long after you posted them.

An obvious place to start improving older content are those **answers to very popular questions**. it's also a good start when looking for answers to enhance with further details, explanation, and instructions – all else being equal, **your time is probably best spent on the most viewed content**.

But with the *views* sort order gone, this is very difficult to determine*.
**Please bring back the *views* sort order for answers in the user profile.**

Maybe just call it *question views* instead, to avoid confusion?

[image: Screenshot of "question views" sort order UI]

<sub>* [Here's a Data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/82307/your-answers-by-question-views). In fact, it seems Data.SE is the only solution, as `user:me is:answer` cannot be sorted by views, and filtering with the `views:` operator doesn't work for the reason stated in the second paragraph.</sub>